# Mariadb 10.4.24 status shows [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.4

When I run the command `sudo systemctl status mariadb` I get the following screen with a warning in red.

[image]

This happened when I did an upgrade from Mariadb 10.3 to 10.4.24

This is  [my.cnf](https://pastebin.com/L9QYdKQ5).
I am not sure if this warning will have consequences.

I am certain that the root password is okay. I am able to login and list the users as shown below as well as perform other tasks such as create other users, create db and tables
[image: The mariadb status]

Any assistance in resolving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: check your `etc/selinux/config` if selinux is `enforcing`, `disabled` it and reboot it.

Comment: Its an SQL error, not selinux. Don't disable selinux. This is likely a postupgrade step that isn't working because the root password was changed. What distro/version are you running?

Comment: @danblack Thanks for your quick response. Yes there was a root password change that I did. My distro is Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS kernel version 5.4.0-100-generic

Comment: Seems this issue has been resolved after I stopped the mariadb server and started it again. Don't understand what changed.